# What determines if a site is secure to browsers?

Tags: web-services, security, web, server

I'm currently building a web site, and I wanted to know how to ensure that my website appeared as secure in a browser.

Kind of like Facebook:
[image: "The security."]

See how they have that little green secure lock icon (in Chrome)? How can I achieve that on my own website to ensure it's users feel comfortable?

Comment: You do know that you have to pay in order to gain HTTPS, right ? You can't just add a code and that's that...

Comment: By making it secure /s But seriously, it's a bad sign that you spend more thought on the *appearance* of security rather than actually achieving security. Plus, the padlock indicates HTTPS, which is transport security, nothing more.

Comment: @delnan I like the way you put the problem "spend more thought on the appearance of security rather than actually achieving security" :))

Comment: Oh, no, I have security on my site and everything. I spend months learning about XSS attacks and the like. But not matter what happens, my site still stands mediocre.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your browser will display this icon when you navigate to a secured endpoint for the website by using the https scheme instead of http. The browser will connect to port 443 on the server instead of port 80 and will receive one or more [certificates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_certificate) from the server.

These certificates form a chain, where one certificate is verified by including the digital signature of a signing authority whose public key is included in another certificate.

Eventually, this chain of trust ends in a certificate that is signed by a signing authority whose public key is included in your browser distribution, so the browser is hardcoded to trust it. If the browser is able to build this chain of trust all the way to a build-in public key, it will display this icon to indicate to the user that the site belongs to whoever the certificate was issued for.

If you click this icon, the browser will display a dialog in which you can find who the certificate was issued to (Subject) and the certificates that build this chain of trust.

See also: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20803/how-does-ssl-tls-work and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security

Answer (score 0):

You need to have SSL installed on your server.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use SSL , request to your hosting provider fyi, this is paid services, but few hosting provider give you free SSL services Alpha SSL.